# Why does vedic calculation doesn't match up with modern times?

Tags: puranas, astrology

According to Bhavishya Puran, we have the below-stated breakup. According to the Harvard Database of Useful Biological Numbers, a blink can last between 100 and 400 milliseconds. Even if, we consider that a blink of an eye at the minimum of 100 milliseconds then also, 1 year doesn't sum up to be 86400 seconds [1 second = 1000 milliseconds].

> The blink of an eye is called Nimesh (100 milliseconds)

> 18 Nimesh = Kashta (1800 milliseconds or 1.8 seconds)

> 30 Kashta = 1 Kala (54000 milliseconds or 54 seconds)

> 30 Kala = 1 Shan (1620000 milliseconds or 1620 seconds)

> 12 Shan = 1 Murat (19440000 milliseconds or 19440 seconds)

> 30 Murat = day and night (583200000 milliseconds or  583200 seconds)

> 30 Day/Night = Month (Mahina)(17496000000 milliseconds or 17496000 seconds)

> 2 Mahina (month) = 1 Ritu (34992000000 milliseconds or 34992000 seconds)

> 3 Rita = 1 Ayan (104976000000 milliseconds or 104976000 seconds)

> 2 Ayan = Year (209952000000 milliseconds or 209952000 seconds) or 58320 hrs = 2430 days or **6.65 years**

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/57686/hinduism-rejects-or-accepts-evolution-theory/57707

Comment: Related2: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2818/29449

Comment: @Ubi.B Can you put the source for these quotes? Maybe the verse numbers from Bhavishya Puraana?

Answer (score 1):

**I think,** the topic should not be how accurate they are but it should be how close they are in terms of accuracy.

- A [Muhurta](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/muhurta#vaishnavism) is considered to be 48 mins = 2880 secs.

MBH 12:231.11-13:

> “Vyasa said, ‘Only Brahman, which is without beginning and without end, unborn, blazing with effulgence, above decay, immutable, indestructible, inconceivable, and transcending knowledge, exists before the Creation.  The Rishis, measuring time, have named particular portions by particular names. Five and ten winks of the eye make what is called a Kashtha. Thirty Kashthas would make what is called a Kala.Thirty Kalas, with the tenth part of a Kala added, make what is known as a Muhurta. Thirty Muhurtas make up one day and night. Thirty days and nights are called a month, and twelve months are called a year.

Again, Manu Smriti 1.64.:

> Ten and eight ‘nimeṣas’ (should be known as) one ‘Kāṣṭhā’; thirty such (Kāṣṭhās) one ‘Kalā’; thirty ‘Kalās’ one ‘muhūrta’; and as many ‘muhūrtas’ one ‘Ahorātra’ (Day and Night).

The difference can be seen in the nimesas. Where one says 15 and other says 18.

As mentioned in question only a blink can varie from 100 milli secs (0.1 s) to 400 milli secs (0.4secs).

So, if we reverse calculate it keeping the muhurta 48 mins. In case of 15 blinks, 1 blink came out to be around 0.2134 secs and for 18 blinks it's around 0.178 secs.

I guess that's not bad. Actually, it's pretty close and good.

Now, Let's see another one.

Shiva Purana 2.1.10.:

> 21-22. In the case of **all living beings,** Brahmā, Viṣṇu, Harā, Gandharvas, serpents, Rākṣasas, etc., **twenty one thousand six hundred respirations constitute the period of one day and one night,** O foremost among Devas.
>
> 23-24. Six respirations constitute the period of time one Pala. Sixty such Palas constitute one Ghaṭī. Sixty Ghaṭīs constitute one day and one night. (6 x 60 x 60 = 21600). There is no limit to the number of respirations of Sadāśiva. Hence He is undecaying.

And, interestingly these 21600 breaths of a whole day if converted mathematically it becomes 24 hours in modern terms. See below.:

- **Note.: s = seconds, b = breaths, p = palas, g = ghatis, m = minutes, h = hours, d = day.**
- Pala (पल).— Unit of time equivalent to 24 seconds.
- So, 1b = 24s ÷ 6b = 4s.
- Nos. of seconds in a day as per as scriptures = 4s × 6b × 60p × 60g = 86,400s.
- Nos. of seconds in 24 hours = 60s × 60m × 24h = 86,400s.
- Therefore, 21,600b = 24h = 1d.

You can also check [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50113/20968) answer of mine for more.

I hope this helps. Prd..